QR Code Scanning Issue Causing Duplicate Entries and Intents on Initial Scan
In certain devices, an issue occurs where the QR code is scanned twice during the first scan after the app is started. This results in two entries being made in the database and two intents being triggered. The problem resolves itself for subsequent scans until the app is restarted, at which point the issue reappears on the first scan. Additionally, user experience some lag during the scanning process. This problem is inconsistent and only affects specific devices.
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>
    private var isProcessingScan = false
    private var cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
    private val processedBarcodes = mutableSetOf<String>()
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        permissionManager.checkAndRequestCameraPermission(
            onPermissionGranted = {
                cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                    val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                    bindCameraUseCases(cameraProvider)
                }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
            },
        )

        binding.toggleScanner.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            permissionManager.checkAndRequestCameraPermission(
                onPermissionGranted = {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        startBarcodeScanner()
                    }
                    else{
                        startQRScanner()
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
     private fun bindCameraUseCases(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
        Log.d("HomeFragment1", "bindCameraUseCases called")
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)

        val layoutParams = binding.frameScanner.layoutParams
        val isLandscape = resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE

        val scanner = if (binding.toggleScanner.isChecked) {

            binding.frameScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.barcode_scanner_overlay)

            if (isLandscape) {
                layoutParams.width = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(_380sdp)
                layoutParams.height = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(_80sdp)
            } else {
                layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            }

            BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(
                    Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_128,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_39,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_93,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_CODABAR,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_13,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_EAN_8,
                    Barcode.TYPE_ISBN,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_ITF,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_UPC_A,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_UPC_E,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_PDF417,
                    Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC,
                )
                .build()
        }
        else {
            binding.frameScanner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.qr_scanner_overlay)
            layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

            BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
                .build()
        }

        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display?.rotation ?: Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
            .build()

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext())) { imageProxy ->
            processImageProxy(scanner, imageProxy)
        }

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageAnalysis
        )
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
    private fun processImageProxy(scannerOptions: BarcodeScannerOptions, imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        Log.d("HomeFragment", "processImageProxy called with isProcessingScan: $isProcessingScan")

        if (isProcessingScan) {
            imageProxy.close()
            return
        }

        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: return
        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

        val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(scannerOptions)
        scanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                if (barcodes.isNotEmpty()) {
                    handleScannedResult(barcodes[0])
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                imageProxy.close()
            }
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                imageProxy.close()

            }
    }

    private fun handleScannedResult(barcode: Barcode) {
        val result = barcode.rawValue
        val barcodeType = barcode.format
        if (result != null) {
            if (processedBarcodes.contains(result)) {
                return
            }
            processedBarcodes.add(result)
            isProcessingScan = true

            val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            val time = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

            lifecycleScope.launch {
                val historyItem = HistoryItemEntity(
                    content = result,
                    date = date,
                    time = time,
                    resultType = "scanned",
                    barcodeType = getBarcodeTypeName(barcodeType)
                )
                AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext()).historyDao().insertHistoryItem(historyItem)
            }

            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), ResultActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("SCANNED_RESULT", result)
                putExtra("BARCODE_TYPE", getBarcodeTypeName(barcodeType))
            }
            startActivity(intent)

            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                isProcessingScan = false
                processedBarcodes.clear()
            }, 6000)
        }
    }

    private fun startQRScanner() {
        isProcessingScan = false
        processedBarcodes.clear()
        bindCameraUseCases(cameraProviderFuture.get())
    }

    private fun startBarcodeScanner() {
        isProcessingScan = false
        processedBarcodes.clear()
        bindCameraUseCases(cameraProviderFuture.get())
    }


Can you reproduce the issue on a local device? If not, please investigate which devices are affected and if there is a pattern. It might for example only occur on a specific Android version or vendor.

@BenjyTec I have used other QR scanner apps, and they work fine on that device, but the issue occurs only with my app.

You said this: This problem is inconsistent and only affects specific devices. On which specific devices does it occur?

@BenjyTec I have used a Samsung device with Android version 14. I also tested the same version on other Samsung and Vivo devices, and it works fine, but the issue occurs only on the first device.

@BenjyTec The affected model is the Galaxy F13.

@BenjyTec any solution?

If it only happens on that one device, then add breakpoints to your code, connect your F13 to the PC with USB Debugging enabled, start the app in debugging mode, and then see exactly what is happening. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug With such specific cases, there will very likely not be a direct answer available here on stackoverflow.
